# Posting/Getting Data with Structs while using Firebase's .childByAutoID() to generate IDs

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

To add a new tweet to Firebase, I'm creating a new Tweet struct each time, creating a dictionary, then pushing the dictionary into Firebase using "setValue". To generate a "tweetID", I'm using Firebase's "childByAutoID" which means I don't know the ID beforehand. However, when I go to get the Tweets so that I can display them on the client side, I'd ideally like to pull out the raw data and put it back into a Tweet struct, which lacks an "tweetID" property.

I thought about including "tweetID" to the Tweet struct as an optional/setting it to nil initially (commented out below), then setting it when I go to retrieve the tweet, but I wanted to see if there was a better way.

```
struct Tweet {
    // tweetID: String?
    createdAt: String
    message: String
    creator: String

    func createDict() -> [String : String] {
        return [
            "createdAt": self.createdAt,
            "message": self.message,
            "creator": self.creator
        ]
    }
}
```

Hopefully, this makes sense. Please let me know if it doesn't and I'll try to clarify. Am I thinking about this the right way? I'm interested in hearing about how you guys have dealt with this issue in the past? Thanks in advance!